# What does the letter epsilon signify in mathematics?

Tags: notation

This letter "$\varepsilon$" is called epsilon right ? What does it signify in mathematics ?

Comment: Traditionally $\epsilon$ is used together with $\delta$ in the definition of limit, where it denotes an arbitrarily small quantity. Else, it is just a symbol that you can attach basically to anything.

Comment: @AndreaMori so how does ϵ differe from δ because both are used to signify arbitrarily small quantity ?

Comment: First of all, I didn't say that $\delta$ is arbitrarily small. Second, if you have several independent quantities, whatevere big or small they are, you need as many symbols, don't you?

Comment: If you don't say where you saw it, we can't give you more helpful answers...

Comment: Not much. $ $ $ $

Comment: Paul Erdős used it to mean children as "How are the epsilons?"

Comment: see also wikipedia Epsilon(disambiguation) > Science and mathematics https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_%28disambiguation%29#Science_and_mathematics , many uses for a symbol

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The greek letter epsilon, written $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$, is just another variable, like $x$, $n$ or $T$.

Conventionally it's used to denote a small quantity, like an error, or perhaps a term which will be taken to zero in some limit.

It's possible that you are confusing it with the set membership symbol $\in$, which is something different. When you see $x\in X$ it means that $X$ is a set, and $x$ is a member of the set. For example,

$$1\in \{1,2,3\}$$

is true, but

$$4\in\{1,2,3\}$$

is false.

Comment: Historically, the symbol $\in$ is derived from $\epsilon$, thus it is not impossible to confuse both symbols. Also, not as ubiquitous as its primary usage, this Greek symbol $\epsilon$ or $\varepsilon$ is also used to denote the sign, including Levi-Civita symbol in physics and random sign in probability to name a few.

Comment: Presumably it's $\epsilon$ for "element"..?

Comment: A little research tells me that the symbol $\epsilon$ for set membership was first used by Peano in 1889, and he said that the $\epsilon$ stood for the Latin word *est*, meaning "it is" or "it exists". The more you know...

Comment: @sos440: not impossible?

Comment: @NickKidman $\neg\neg p = p$

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: Most of the times, yes. Anyway, I was thinking he wanted to say the opposite, as it's posted in response to you post.

Comment: Actually in books from the 50's you can still see $\varepsilon$ being used for $\in$. This is why often you *hear* people talk about "epsilon relation" or "epsilon induction".

Comment: In formal language theory, $\varepsilon$ is sometimes used to signify the empty word.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor Latin *est* can mean “it is,” but more accurately it is the third-person (i.e. not the speaker or the audience but some “third” person), singular, present-tense form of the (irregular) verb *esse*, “to be, to exist.” Because the form of the verb already indicates the subject is third-person singular, Latin rarely supplied a separate subject unless necessary—hence “it” is implicit in the form of the verb. But when a subject is necessary—as in $x\ ϵ\ \{1, 2, 3\}$—you would use the subject, *x*, not “it.” So “*x* est {1, 2, 3}” is “*x* is {1, 2, 3}.”

Answer (score 5):

[Hilbert's epsilon-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_calculus) used the letter $\varepsilon$ to denote a value satisfying a predicate. If $\phi(x)$ is any property, then $\varepsilon x. \phi(x)$ is a term $t$ such that $\phi(t)$ is true, if such $t$ exists. One can define the usual existential and universal quantifiers $\exists$ and $\forall$ in terms of the $\varepsilon$ quantifier:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\def\hil#1{#1(\varepsilon x. #1(x))}
\exists x.\phi(x) & \equiv  & \hil{\phi}\\
\forall x.\phi(x) & \equiv  & \phi(\varepsilon x.\lnot\phi(x))
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: The Hilbert epsilon also proves the axiom of choice.  If $\forall x.\exists y.\phi(x,y)$, then $\forall x.\phi(x,\varepsilon y.\phi(x,y))$.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a not too well-known instance of the use of $\varepsilon$ in mathematics:

One somewhat well-known transformation for accelerating the convergence of a sequence is the [Shanks transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanks_transformation) (after [Daniel Shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Shanks), who is probably more well-known for his number-theoretic contributions). What the Shanks transformation essentially does, assuming that the sequence given is a sequence of Taylor polynomials evaluated at a certain argument, is to transform this sequence of Taylor approximants into a sequence of [Padé rational approximants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).

The Shanks transformation of a sequence can be expressed as a ratio of two determinants, but there is a more efficient realization of this, the [Wynn $\varepsilon$ algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0025-5718-1956-0084056-6):

$$\varepsilon_{k+1}^{(n)}=\varepsilon_{k-1}^{(n+1)}+\frac1{\varepsilon_{k}^{(n+1)}-\varepsilon_k^{(n)}}$$

where $\varepsilon_0^{(n)}=S_n$ is the sequence to be transformed.